# How to export only certain functions from linux SO library?

Tags: c++, linux, dll, c++11, shared-libraries

When creating a Windows DLL one can easily choose exported symbols (using dllexport). In such situation symbols not exported are not visible outside the library. How can one get the same functionality on Linux?
In other words:
Let's say I have 10 functions in a project. Three of them should be exported, and the remaining 7 are helper functions that should not be usable from library API. How do i create SO file in such way, that lets me achive that?

Comment: Assuming you're using GCC, [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) should help.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/GCC by default everything is exported (depending on language rules, of course: something in an anonymous namespace will never be exported).

If you want to stop a symbol from being exported, you can use `__attribute__((__visibility__("hidden")))`. For example:

```
__attribute__((__visibility__("hidden"))) void myPrivateFunction();
```